# Making a New way to Register on checkout/checkout

Tags: php, opencart

Hey guys im trying to put some customer information on checkout/checkout - telephone, birthady, cellphone
About register.php only email and password. 
**But the problem is i can't save on database except firstname, lastname**
Opencart 2.3.0.2 Im making all on default template but i've the themeforest template

So on tpl i put this on payment_adress

```
<div class="telefone required col-lg-6" style="padding-left: 0;">
                   <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="input-telephone"><?php //echo $entry_telephone; ?></label> 
                  <div class="col-sm-12 inputWithIcon">                     
                     <input type="text" name="telephone" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_telephone; ?>" id="input-payment-telephone" class="form-control" title="Coloque o número de telefone celular ou fixo" required="required"/>
                     <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                 </div>
```

on Controller payment_adress

```
$data['entry_telephone'] = $this->language->get('entry_telephone');
```

and

```
if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) > 32)) {
                $json['error']['telephone'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone');
            }
```

and on Model address i make another public function called addCustomer2. The purpose is INSERT INTO customer all information. So is this file i put

```
public function addCustomer2($data) {
    if (isset($data['customer_group_id']) && is_array($this->config->get('config_customer_group_display')) && in_array($data['customer_group_id'], $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
        $customer_group_id = $data['customer_group_id'];
    } else {
        $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
    }

    $this->load->model('account/customer_group');

    $customer_group_info = $this->model_account_customer_group->getCustomerGroup($customer_group_id);

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "', store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "', language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "', firstname = '" . strtoupper($this->db->escape($data['firstname'])) . "', lastname = '" . strtoupper($this->db->escape($data['lastname'])) . "', telephone = '" . $this->db->escape($data['telephone']) . "', custom_field = '" . $this->db->escape(isset($data['custom_field']['account']) ? json_encode($data['custom_field']['account']) : '') . "', salt = '" . $this->db->escape($salt = token(9)) . "', ip = '" . $this->db->escape($this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "', status = '1', approved = '" . (int)!$customer_group_info['approval'] . "', date_added = NOW()");}
```

There's no message error about my configuration, but is not saving the informations. 
Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked if in controller is called model function addCustomer2  (not addCustomer)

From what i understand from your message (if you don't get any errors) seems in controller is called old function addCustomer, not your new function.

Also if you have some OCMOD extensions and that model was changed make sure to check storage/modification/... and to rebuild ocmod cache (if you changed a file which was also modified by other ocmod extensions)

Have a nice day

Comment: You're right the solution was put addCustomer2 not addCustomer. Is this case i put addAdress2. What i did was make a new coke updating oc_customer when the customer text firstname, lastname and telephone. So at the same file model/account/address.php i changed the way to save information. The purpose of this code is: on register.tpl request only email and password. When the customer put a product on cart, he'll redirected to checkout/checkout and then he should put all the informations: fist and lastname, telephone and the complete address.